# Find Volume of a Wineglass - a Slice

Tags: recreational-mathematics

A spherical wineglass, known diameter, is brim full of wine. What is the width of any vertical parallel slice with a volume of 1/4 of the wine?

Assume that the height of the wineglass is known.

Comment: "Spherical wineglass".. how is it meant? can we assume it is a full sphere, or chopped?

Comment: Spherical wineglasses would be rather frustrating, methinks ...

Comment: The wineglass is chopped

Comment: The problem requires a formula where one cut face would be defined, it can be in the centre or elsewhere.

Comment: Perhaps you mean a hemispherical wineglass?

Comment: Does the height of the wineglass include the stem of the glass?

Comment: The wineglass is greater than a hemisphere. It does not include the stem.

Comment: What curve are you calling a wineglass?

Comment: Put a picture, please.

Answer (score 1):

Use the disk (washer) method for the function $f(x):=\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$  on the interval $[x_0,x_0+h]\subset[-R,R]$ to get an equation satisfied by $x_0$ and $h$.